# How to set PreferenceFragment with Dark theme

Tags: android, android-layout

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>
</resources>
```

The above code does not change my setting preferences color schema.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Which android version of your device?Can override AppBaseTheme in values-v11 or values-14?

Answer (score 0):

You must apply your theme in manifest in `application` tag :

```
<application
            android:name=".app.MyApp"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/my_label"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below in your styles.xml

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"/>
```

and add the below in your setting activity declaration in Manifest.xml.

```
android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"
```

Hope this solves your issue.